# How do I use a specific set of words when specifying types for columns in SQLite, using Kotlin?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

I am making a database, and I want one of the fields to either be 'Classic' or 'Current'. How do I create a table with a column that will specify only the two of those?

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val CREATE_SONGS_TABLE = ("CREATE TABLE $SONGS_TABLE_NAME (" +
        "$COLUMN_SONGID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "$COLUMN_SONG_MODE TEXT CHECK ('Classic', 'Current'), +" +
        "")
    }
```

Please ignore the wrong brackets and all, I will close them properly once I finish the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you want :-

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    val CREATE_SONGS_TABLE = ("CREATE TABLE $SONGS_TABLE_NAME (" +
    "$COLUMN_SONGID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
    "$COLUMN_SONG_MODE TEXT CHECK ($COLUMN_SONG_MODE = 'Classic' OR $COLUMN_SONG_MODE ='Current'))"
}
```

However, it only enforces that only one of the two values is supplied. It will not change an incorrect value. That is, **CHECK** is a constraint (a rule) that if broken will result in a constraint conflict. Although you can use `INSERT OR IGNORE .....` and the conflict will be ignored and with the row not being inserted.

You can also use the slightly different and perhaps more logical :-

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    val CREATE_SONGS_TABLE = ("CREATE TABLE $SONGS_TABLE_NAME (" +
    "$COLUMN_SONGID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
    "$COLUMN_SONG_MODE TEXT, /*<<<<<<<< comma added*/ CHECK ($COLUMN_SONG_MODE = 'Classic' OR $COLUMN_SONG_MODE ='Current'))"
}
```

- This makes the CHECK constraint a table level definition rather than a column level. However, the end result is no different.
- The comment indicating the addition of the comma is only shown to indicate the subtle change. It can be removed.
- Note that the AUTOINCREMENT keyword has been removed, there is very little chance that it is required and it is inefficient as per

  - > *The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.*
    >
    > - [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)